# Insert if NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: mysql, php

I am trying to copy data from table to another mysql table from two different databases 
First I get all data from first table and stored them into php variable 
then I loop on that var to insert data to the other table 
using this query

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`nUserId`, `vLoginName`, `vFirstName`, `vLastName`, `vEmail`)
    VALUES ('$entity_id','$name','$firstname','$lastname','$email') 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `nUserId`,`vEmail`
                      FROM `users`
                      WHERE `nUserId`='$entity_id' 
                      AND   `vEmail` = '$email')
```

but it's not working

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `nUserId`,`vEmail` FROM users '
```

What the correct syntax to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement.
However, you may use `INSERT IGNORE` if in your targer table you define nUserId or vEmail as unique keys.

More info about INSERT syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` can also have unwanted side effects in other cases (values not good for the columns, etc.) It may not be the best choice. In your link: *"Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, **invalid values are adjusted to the closest values and inserted**; warnings are produced but the statement does not abort."*

Comment: @Jehad Keriaki Thanks man it's working now `INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` 
  SET `nUserId`='$entity_id',
   `vLoginName`='$name',
   `vFirstName`='$firstname',
   `vLastName`='$lastname',
   `vEmail`='$email'`

Comment: As an advice, read my comment above and if you care for your data don't use `INSERT IGNORE`. Either use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or the query by @SQLHound.

Comment: If you don't believe me, read this answer by **[Bill Karwin](https://www.percona.com/blog/author/bill-karwin/)**: [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be VALUES and I would write the statement as the following:

```
INSERT INTO `users` 
    (`nUserId`, `vLoginName`, `vFirstName`, `vLastName`, `vEmail`)
SELECT 
    '$entity_id', '$name', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email' 
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM `users`
                    WHERE `nUserId`='$entity_id' 
                    AND   `vEmail` = '$email')
```

Comment: *The* solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like

```
delimiter $$
create procedure select_or_insert()
begin
  IF EXISTS (select * from users where username = 'something') THEN
    update users set id= 'some' where username = 'something';
 ELSE 
insert into users (username) values ('something');
  END IF;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Good solution: easy to understand and read

Answer (score 1):

No need to store them in php.

Creates a table excactly like the one specified, Note: copies only columns

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name LIKE db_name.tbl_name;
```

If you want specific column names:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name SELECT column_name, column_name FROM db_name.tbl_name;
```

Then if you want to copy all the data do

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name SELECT * FROM db_name.tbl_name;
```

Or specific column data do

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name SELECT column_name, column_name FROM db_name.tbl_name;
```

If you want specific data add a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$existeEmail=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE email = '$email'");
 if(!$existeEmail=mysqli_fetch_array($existeEmail))/*si existe en la tabla tblreseteopass*/
{



}else{
    $email = $existeEmail['email'];
      // Direccionado hacia el registro con la Alerta 001
            // ya existe una cuenta asociada a este email, si no recuerda la contraseña, solicite una nueva
            header("Location: https://www.yourpage.com/b/?m=f_lg);
}
```

Comment: Hola Jorge. Acqui, we normally write in English! If you can't do that, then use Google translate or similar to get your Spanish into English. p.s. Benvenido en el forum! :-)