# How to check record if exists before insert with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a record:

```
insert into posts(id, title, body) values(1, 'First post', 'Awesome');
```

If the `First post` title and `Awesome` body already exist in the db, I want to ignore it.

When create a table, it's possible to use `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax. For inserting, is there an easy way?

Comment: @Charlieface It's for MySQL. PostgreSQL doesn't have `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: What about this link then https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30499/optimal-way-to-ignore-duplicate-inserts

Comment: @Charlieface I found this way: https://koalatea.io/postgres-insert-ignore/ But `On CONFLICT(column1, ....)` need unique index. It seems it's necessary to create multiple column unique index to do.

Comment: Not sure why you say that, it depends how many columns you want to check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert if NOT EXISTS not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101413/insert-if-not-exists-not-working)

Comment: @mustaccio - this is an answer related to mysql and not postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create a unique key constraint on title & body columns, you can use insert statement as below to ignore if record already exists

```
insert into posts(id, title, body) values (1, 'First post', 'Awesome') on conflict (title, body) do nothing;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's basically as you say:

```sql
insert into posts (id, title, body) 
 select 1, 'First post', 'Awesome' 
 where not exists (
  select null from posts 
  where (title, body) = ('First post', 'Awesome')
 )
```

You could also define a unique constraint on `(title, body)` and simply ignore the corresponding exception in your program.

In either case, if your application has more than one thread trying to do the same thing, you'll need to make sure it can handle errors properly.

Comment: Why is `select null from posts`? Isn't it `select * from posts`?

Comment: Because you don't need anything from that table except the fact that there is (or isn't) a matching row.

Comment: If use `select null`, even the record doesn't exist in the table, I can't create it. But `select *` works.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra: it's next to impossible that `select *` makes a difference in a sub-query used with an `EXISTS` condition. The value is completely ignored (you can even use `select 1/0` without it throwing an error)